# Suppose $f$ is a differentiable and increasing function on [0,1] such that $f(0)<0<f(1)$. Let $F(t) = \int_0^tf(x)dx$.

Tags: functions

The options provided are :
A) $F$ is an increasing function 
B) $F$ is an decreasing function
C) F has a unique maximum in the the open interval (0,1)
D) F has a unique minimum in the open interval (0,1)

I want to check all the options here, can anyone explain each?

Comment: Try using the fundamental theorem of calculus or actually more precisely the anti-derivative theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$F'(t)=f(t)$$

The derivative of $F$ which is $f$ takes both positive and negative value, hence it cannot be increasing or decreasing and it must attain $0$ at some point.

$$F"(t)=f'(t)$$

Given that $f(t)$ is increasing, $f'(t)>0$, and hence $F"(t) >0$. Hence $F$ is strictly convex.

Comment: Just perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since $$F(t) = \int_0^tf(x)dx \implies F'(t) = f(t)$$

Now, since $f$ is negative at $t=0$ and positive at $t=1$, $\exists ~ c \in (0,1)$ such that $f(c)=0$

From this, we can conclude that the function $F$ has an extremum in the interval $(0,1)$. To find whether it's maxima or minima, check the sign of $F''(c)$ if it is positive, it means $c$ is a minima, else it is a maxima.

$$F'(t)=f(t) \implies F''(t)=f'(t)$$

Since $f$ is increasing function, $f'>0 \implies F''>0$, i.e. $F''(c) >0$.

Hence $c$ is a local minima for the function  $F(t)$

Comment: Okay thanks Jaideep.

Comment: Welcome Iti Shree :-)